# Appropriate data structure for counting frequency of string

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have a task of counting frequency of strings(words) in a text file. What data structure do you think is appropriate(based on implementation difficulty, memeory usage and time complexity of algorithm)? I have hash-table, bunary search tree and heap in mind but I don't know which one to choose? Also if there is any better data structure than the ones I mentioned, it will be great too. Thanks in advance.
N.B. the text file could be extremely large.

Comment: Do you count the frequency of each word of the text file, or only a small subset ? What do you want to optimize ?

Comment: "N.B. the text file could be extremely large." My largest dictionary word list text file is only about 4Mb. Unless the input text file contains random gibberish, that's all you'll get from any size of input. You don't need the entire input file in memory.

Comment: "the text file could be extremely large" does that mean *larger than available memory*?

Comment: If you're counting the frequency of each word in a text file the dictionary would be the best option as it has O(1) complexity for search when you update the count.

Comment: A hash table is probably ideal. You could store items as key-value pairs of string + frequency counter. It will have roughly the same access time per item, mostly depending on how good a hash function you create.

Comment: @AloisChristen yeah the frequency of each word  in the text file. The text file could contain as large as 4 billion distinct words and there might be around 2 billion repetitions of each word in worst case scenario.

Comment: @SupportUkraine yeah, the text file could contain as large as 4 billion distinct words and there might be around 2 billion repetitions of each word in worst case scenario.

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean the text file could contain around 4 billion distinct words and each distinct word could have at most 2 billion repetitions(0 repetitions atleast)

Comment: If you need to repeat the same information to 3 different comment, you should edit the question to add that information.

Comment: 4 billion *distinct* words seems fanciful. What do you define as a "word" and as "distinct word"?

Comment: I words are somewhat similar, you can look at ternary search tree, which might reduce memory usage.

Comment: You could look into a trie.

Answer (score 1):

Because you say the file could be extremely large, I assumed you can't keep all the words in memory simultaneously.

Note that if the file had all words sorted, finding the frequencies would require keeping only the counter and two last words in memory at a time to compare them. As long as the same word as before is read, increment the counter. When you hit a different word, save the previous word and its count to another file with the frequencies and start counting over for the new word.

So the question is how to sort words in a file. For that purpose, you can use merge sort. Note that when merging subarrays, it's needed to keep only two words in memory, one per subarray. Additionally, you will need to create an extra file, like an extra array in in-memory merge sort, and play with positions in files. If you write to the original and extra files alternately in recursive calls, these two will be enough.